# Find the value from XML data in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I want to find the value from XML data in SQL Server table.

Below is my sample xmldata;

```
<wddxPacket version="1.0">
   <header />
   <data>
      <struct type="xyz">
         <var name="TXRGHC43">
            <string />
         </var>
         <var name="TWBS1">
             <string>9011750</string>
         </var>
         <var name="PMNAMEID">
            <string>2323443</string>
         </var>

         <var name="EDATE36">
            <string />
         </var>

         <var name="TWBSDESC40">
            <string />
         </var>

      </struct>
   </data>
</wddxPacket>
```

I am searching for **9011750** under **TWBS1**. can you please help me on this. how to find **9011750** value.

I am trying the following queries but I didn't get any output.

```
select
  col
from
  xyz
where
  col.value('(/wddxPacket/data/struct/var[TWBS1])[2]', 'varchar(max)') like '9011750'

SELECT col.value('(/wddxPacket/data/struct/var/string)[3]', 'varchar(100)')
FROM   xyz
```

my requirement is to search the data entire table, that is only sample xml data.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following SQL. It shows how to use a predicate in the *XPath* expression to simulate `WHERE` clause.

> SQL

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, xmldata XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl (xmldata)
VALUES
(N'<wddxPacket version="1.0">
    <header/>
    <data>
        <struct type="xyz">
            <var name="TXRGHC43">
                <string/>
            </var>
            <var name="TWBS1">
                <string>9011750</string>
            </var>
            <var name="PMNAMEID">
                <string>2323443</string>
            </var>
            <var name="EDATE36">
                <string/>
            </var>
            <var name="TWBSDESC40">
                <string/>
            </var>
        </struct>
    </data>
</wddxPacket>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @varName VARCHAR(20) = 'TWBS1';

SELECT c.value('(./text())[1]','INT') AS [string_value]
FROM @tbl AS tbl
    CROSS APPLY tbl.xmldata.nodes('/wddxPacket/data/struct/var[@name=sql:variable("@varName")]/string') AS t(c);
```

> Output

```
+--------------+
| string_value |
+--------------+
|      9011750 |
+--------------+
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. but  my requirement is to search the data entire table in that perticular column, not static.

Comment: I adjusted the answer, and made the parameter dynamic via SQL Server variable. The SELECT statement will work with the entire table. Nothing is static here.